# Instantiation of virtual member function with templated return type

Tags: c++11, templates, visual-c++

I have a base class (with which I want to simulate interfaces)

```
template<typename TType>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual SomeTemplatedClass<TType> GetTheObject() = 0;
}
```

and obviously a derived class

```
template<typename TType>
class Derived : public Base<TType>
{
public:
    virtual SomeTemplatedClass<TType> GetTheObject() = 0;
}
```

but for some specific type I have the intention to specialize the 'GetTheObject'

```
template<> 
SomeTemplatedClass<int> Derived<int>::GetTheObject()
{
    return 5;
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 complains it *cannot instantiate abstract class*, when I try to use

```
Derived<int>
```

Providing even a throwing behavior to a template version

```
class Derived : public Base<TType>
{
public:
    virtual SomeTemplatedClass<TType> GetTheObject() override
    {
        throw <something>;
    }
}
```

Let everything compile.
So my question is: **Why do i need to provide a generic behavior, when I have a specific one and the only one that is needed?**

Comment: Remove the `=0` specifier from the declaration of `GetTheObject()` in `Derived`.   That forces the function to be pure virtual.   Defining the function does not change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to *implement* the generic GetTheObject, but you need to *declare* it as non-pure. Otherwise your class is abstract.

```
template<typename TType>
class Derived : public Base<TType>
{
public:
     virtual SomeTemplatedClass<TType> GetTheObject();
}
```

You can specialise the function now.

You won't be able to instantiate any non-specialised derived objects (you will get linker errors).

You cannot make an abstract class into concrete by simply providing an implementation of its pure virtual member outside of the class.

```
class A { virtual void f() = 0; }; // A is abstract
void A::f() {} // A is still abstract
```

Templates are no different.

```
template <int> class A { virtual void f() = 0; }; // A is abstract
template <int k> void A<k>::f() {} // A is still abstract
```

A function specialisation changes nothing.

```
template <int> class A { virtual void f() = 0; }; // A is abstract
template <int k> void A<k>::f() {} // A is still abstract
template <> void A<42>::f() {} // srsly are you kidding?
```

If you want the generic case to be abstract and the specialised case concrete, you need to specialise the entire class, not just the pure function implementation.

Comment: But if this is the only function, shouldn't it just work? Or do you mean i needed to specialize the entire class, not only this member?

Comment: Yes the entire class, I think I wrote it.